# Using dd to restore a partition backup from MBR disk to GPT one

Tags: partition, hard-disk, dd, gpt, mbr

I have an ext4 partition backed up with dd on a MBR hard drive that I would like to restore to a new GPT hard drive. Can I just create an empty partition of the exact same size on that new GPT drive and overwrite that partition with the one I want to restore or I have to do something else because the partition was backed up on a MBR drive?

Thanks.

Edit:
The partition on the MBR hard drive was primary. It was the third partition on the drive. I made the backup with dd.

Comment: Can you provide more details about how you backuped the partition to the MBR Drive and what kind of partitioning was used on the original HDD (if MBR, was the partition a primary or logical partition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I just create an empty partition of the exact same size on that
>   new GPT drive and overwrite that partition with the one I want to
>   restore?

Yes.

The MBR/GPT distinction is metadata stored outside of the partition. So when you made a *partition* backup using `dd` you only backed up the content of that partition (the filesystem), which does not include anything about the partitioning scheme.